# CodeIgniter autoload session is not loading in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I set session as an autoload in config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'template', 'session');
```

and config session and encrypt in config/config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'dornika';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 86400;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

and then I set session data in an array with

```
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

and load this in controller with

`$this->session->userdata('login');`

which contain true
but in my controller it becomes null instead of 1(or true)

here is code in model

```
$is_exist = $this->db->count_all_results();

        if($is_exist > 0){
         $data_session = array(
             'username' => $_POST['username'],
             'login' => true
         );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
            redirect('dashboard/index');
        }else{
            redirect('login');
        }
```

and controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Dashboard extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
       $login = $this->session->userdata('login');
        if ($login == true) {

            $data['title'] = 'dashboard';
            $this->template->load('panel/dashboard', $data);

        }else{
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `$this->session->userdata('login')` which doesn't there, you haven't given any name to your session. You can solve this by giving name to session while setting it.

**Code**

```
# Setting Session
$this->session->set_userdata("login", $array);    

# Accessing Session
$user_data = $this->session->userdata("login");
echo $user_data['some_key']; // or var_dump($user_data);
```

Comment: thank you for answer but I did it before set user data with

$data_session = array(
     'username' => 'username',
     'login' => true
)

Comment: I am not telling about array, I am saying that first argument of `set_userdata()` must be a name that's name of the session. You have to give a name to session to access it later on. `$this->session->set_userdata("example", $array)`

Comment: I don't get any error message it's just not working @Tirth Patel

Comment: __ci_last_regenerate|i:1467335684;    I get this in folder that I set for it.

and steel no session. I change plan and set _session_ in controller
but I can't get it in another controller. I used what;s u said before.